# How to disable buttons as login and register if a user is already logged in

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I want to ensure that when a user is logged in then Login and Register buttons have to be disabled in the view in Laravel. Moreover, I use ready register and login functionality available out of the box of Laravel The code I use:
The view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1 class="h1">Welcome</h1>
<p class="lead"><a href="/login" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Login</a>  <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button" href="/register">Register</a></p>
</div>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement to @Jagjeet Singh's answer if you're using `v5.4.29^`

You can simply do:

```
@auth
    // Authorised.
@else
    // Not authorised.
@endauth
```

OR

```
@guest
   //Not authorised
@else
   //Authorised.
@endguest
```

Using `@auth` you can also parse in a guard like so: `@auth('admin')` if you're using roles as such.

To answer your comment:

```
@guest
    // The HTML below will only show if the user IS NOT logged in to any account.
    <p class="lead"><a href="/login" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Login</a>  <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button" href="/register">Register</a></p>
@endguest
```

Comment: look I want to ensure that after user logs in I want to remove buttons from the view and if user logs out I want restore buttons in the view. How is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Place your buttons inside guest / endguest directives I've shown above. This way they'll only show up if they're not authorised / logged in to any account.

Comment: @Mirasan I've answered your comment above.

Comment: You can find more information about blade templating directives in Laravel [here for 5.7.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#if-statements) or [here for 5.6.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Auth::check` in view

```
@if (Auth::check())
    //Logout Button
@else
    // Login, Register Button
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
<a href="/login" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" {{ auth()->check() ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button" href="/register" {{ auth()->check() ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Register</a>
```

Comment: I have used your code but the same even after I log in the buttons are still enabled

Comment: @Mirasan  try with disabled=disabled

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hideshow-button-on-user-login).

```
@if (Auth::check())
    // The user is logged in...
@endif
@if (Auth::guest())
    // The user is not logged in...
@endif
```